# Haskell primPutChar definition

Tags: haskell, io, definition

I'm trying to figure out how the basic `IO` Haskell functions are defined, so I used [this reference](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html) and I got to the `putChar` function definition:

```
putChar    :: Char -> IO ()
putChar    =  primPutChar
```

Now, however, I cannot find more information about this `primPutChar` function anywhere. Maybe it might refer to a pre-compiled function, available as binary from a shared object? If that's the case, is it possible to see its source code?

Comment: Function name's starting with `prim` means it's a built-in primitive. The definition of such a function cannot be given in terms of Haskell; it also will differ between target platforms. Sometimes it's a foreign function, sometimes it's a function name well known to the compiler (so that it can emit appropriate code directly where the function is called).

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy put your answer as an answer, not comment.

Comment: You can see it in base package: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/System.IO.html#putChar Thanks to the latest haddock, you can navigate it pretty easily!

Comment: @Sibi thanks, that's really interesting! However, why on that place `putChar` is defined in terms of Haskell code, and in the onlinereport they imply it's a primitive function, as @AndreyChernyakhovskiy pointed out? Does the former get compiled once and then shipped inside libraries? EDIT @Zeta just beated me with the answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### What `prim*` means

Since you're asking this question in terms of the report, let's also answer this question in terms of the report:

> Primitives that are not definable in Haskell , indicated by names starting with "`prim`", are defined in a system dependent manner in module `PreludeBuiltin` and are not shown here

This is still the same in [Haskell2010 by the way](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch9.html#x16-1710009).

### How it's implemented in GHC

However, you can [have a look at `base`'s source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/System.IO.html#putChar) to see how it's implemented in GHC:

```
putChar         :: Char -> IO ()
putChar c       =  hPutChar stdout c
```

From there you're going deep into the rabbit hole. How does [`hPutChar`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.Handle.Text.html#hPutChar) know how to print stuff? Well, it doesn't. It only "buffers" and checks that you can write:

```
hPutChar :: Handle -> Char -> IO ()
hPutChar handle c = do
    c `seq` return ()
    wantWritableHandle "hPutChar" handle $ \ handle_  -> do
     hPutcBuffered handle_ c
```

The writing is done in [`writeCharBuffer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.Handle.Internals.html#writeCharBuffer) which fills an internal buffer until it's full (or a line has been reached—it actually depends on the buffer mode):

```
writeCharBuffer h_@Handle__{..} !cbuf = do
  -- much code omitted, like buffering
      bbuf'' <- Buffered.flushWriteBuffer haDevice bbuf'
  -- more code omitted, like buffering
```

So where is [`flushWriteBuffer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.BufferedIO.html#flushWriteBuffer) defined? It's actually part of [`stdout`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.Handle.FD.html#stdout):

```
stdout :: Handle
stdout = unsafePerformIO $ do
   setBinaryMode FD.stdout
   enc <- getLocaleEncoding
   mkHandle FD.stdout "<stdout>" WriteHandle True (Just enc)
                nativeNewlineMode{-translate newlines-}
                (Just stdHandleFinalizer) Nothing
```

```
stdout :: FD
stdout = stdFD 1
```

And a file descriptor (`FD`) is an instance of [`BufferedIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.FD.html#line-126):

```
instance BufferedIO FD where
  -- some code omitted
  flushWriteBuffer  fd buf = writeBuf' fd buf
```

and `writeBuf` uses [`instance GHC.IO.Device.RawIO FD`'s `write`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.FD.html#line-96), and that ultimately [leads to](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.FD.html#writeRawBufferPtr):

```
writeRawBufferPtr loc !fd buf off len
  | isNonBlocking fd = unsafe_write -- unsafe is ok, it can't block
  | otherwise   = do r <- unsafe_fdReady (fdFD fd) 1 0 0
                     if r /= 0
                        then write
                        else do threadWaitWrite (fromIntegral (fdFD fd)); write
  where
    do_write call = fromIntegral `fmap`
                      throwErrnoIfMinus1RetryMayBlock loc call
                        (threadWaitWrite (fromIntegral (fdFD fd)))
    write         = if threaded then safe_write else unsafe_write
    unsafe_write  = do_write (c_write (fdFD fd) (buf `plusPtr` off) len)
    safe_write    = do_write (c_safe_write (fdFD fd) (buf `plusPtr` off) len)
```

where we can see `c_safe_write` and `c_write`, which are usually bindings to C library functions:

```
foreign import capi unsafe "HsBase.h write"
   c_write :: CInt -> Ptr Word8 -> CSize -> IO CSsize
```

So, `putChar` uses [`write`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/write). At least in GHC's implementation. The report however doesn't require that implementation, so another compiler/runtime is allowed to use other functions.

### TL;DR

GHC's implementation uses [`write`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/write) with internal buffers to write things, including single characters.